# What names are valid git tags?

Tags: git, git-tag

I have got a error message while creating tag containing `[` character:

> fatal: '[' is not a valid tag name.

Question: are there any rules for tags in the git?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can check if the name is valid with

```
git check-ref-format
```

This [page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format) contains the constraints on a valid name. Quoted from the page (possibly outdated in the future):

> 1. They can include slash `/` for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but no slash-separated component can begin with a dot `.` or end with the sequence `.lock`.
> 2. They must contain at least one `/`. This enforces the presence of a category like `heads/`, `tags/` etc. but the actual names are not restricted. If the `--allow-onelevel` option is used, this rule is waived.
> 3. They cannot have two consecutive dots `..` anywhere.
> 4. They cannot have ASCII control characters (i.e. bytes whose values are lower than \040, or \177 `DEL`), space, tilde `~`, caret `^`, or colon `:` anywhere.
> 5. They cannot have question-mark `?`, asterisk `*`, or open bracket `[` anywhere. See the `--refspec-pattern` option below for an exception to this rule.
> 6. They cannot begin or end with a slash `/` or contain multiple consecutive slashes (see the `--normalize` option below for an exception to this rule)
> 7. They cannot end with a dot `.`.
> 8. They cannot contain a sequence `@{`.
> 9. They cannot be the single character `@`.
> 10. They cannot contain a `\`.

As you can see, in your case you violated rule (5).

You can use the `--normalize` flag to normalize tags with respect to slashes (removing leading slashes as well as consecutive ones):

```
git check-ref-format --normalize "tags/weird//tag"
```

The `tags/` part species that you are validating a `tag`.

After some discussion with @NikosAlexandris, you can write the following one liner to check the tag `<some-tag>` with textual feedback:

```
git check-ref-format "tags/<some-tag>" && echo "Valid tag" || echo "Invalid tag"
```

Comment: **why** would git impose these **restrictions** on tag names

Comment: @user3245268: because for example you can refer to `remote/branch`, or `HEAD^1` (to get the one but last commit of the head), etc. After all, a tag is just a "special name" for a commit. So in order to make the reference unabiguous between a tag, remote branch, relative path, etc. the names are restricted. On Windows, you can for example not name a file `..`, since then the path `../foo` would have some serious problems. Unix typically solves this with escaping, but here the "tag space", "branch space", "relative commit space" are "merged".

Comment: Rule 2 is wrong. E.g. `v1.4` is a valid tag, accepted by version 2.21.0. See [Git Basics - Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).

Comment: @Arthur: no, since as you can read in your own documentation, if you do it like that, you define a tag named `refs/tags/v1.4`, note that git prepends it with `refs/tags/`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem For the sake of simplicity, most people do not need to follow rule 2 if they're just inputting a tag into GitHub or pushing a tag with git. So I have to agree with Arthur from a "layman's terms" esque standpoint.

Comment: I try to execute command `git tag -- --help`, and got `fatal: '--help' is not a valid tag name.`. While command `git check-ref-format --normalize refs/tags/--help` tells me it's valid.

Answer (score 2):

Disallowed characters: '~', '^', ':', '', '?', '[', '*',

> Also better disable following: '\r', '\n', ' '(whitespace)

Disallowed sequences ".." and "@{"

This symbols/sequences have special meaning to revparse.

---

source: https://libgit2.org/libgit2/#HEAD/group/tag/git_tag_create

additional information: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format

Comment: For me it was invisible new line character in my tag , which was giving me problems.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was invisible new line character in my tag , which was giving me problems.

Comment: Just had the same issue while copying another tag in GitLab