# What is a regex for valid Git tags?

Tags: regex, git

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382234/what-names-are-valid-git-tags) explains what is a valid tag in Git. However, is there a well tested and widely used regular expression that follows these rules?

What is a regex for valid Git tags?

Comment: Which regular expression input language(s) do you allow?

Comment: Ideally .NET, so Perl 5 compatible (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093994/7976758

Comment: @phd That one is actually wrong. It doesn't implement the `.lock` or `.` restrictions correctly. It allows slash-separated components to end with `.lock` and it allows the whole thing to start with `.`.

Comment: Having read that answer (and that thread), I concur with the suggestions to actually run `git check-ref-format`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd translate those rules to Perl regexes:

```
my $base = qr{ [!"#\$%&'()+,\-0-9;<=>\@A-Z\]_`a-z{|}] }x;
```

This is a regex for a single character in the allowed base set. If you want to translate this to another language / regex dialect, note that `$` and `@` are only escaped here because they trigger variable interpolation in Perl.

It's a whitelist because I find it easier to think about things this way. As a side effect, this also disallows any non-ASCII characters.

If you want to allow the full Unicode set, a blacklist becomes easier to work with:

```
my $base = qr{ [^\x00-\x20\x1f~^:?*\[\\] }x;
```

(Or `qr{ [^\x00-\x20\x1f~^:?*\[\\\@] | \@ (?! \{ ) }x` for a version that includes the `@{` restriction; see below.)

```
my $part = qr{ $base+ (?: \. $base+ )* \.? (?<! \.lock ) }x;
```

This matches a single slash-separated part. It implements the restriction that parts cannot start with `.` or contain `..` or end with `.lock`.

```
my $full_ref = qr{\A (?! \@ \z | .* \@\{ ) $part (?: / $part )+ (?<! \. ) \z}sx;
```

This matches a full ref. It adds a few additional restrictions:

- The whole thing cannot be `@`. (This rule is technically redundant because we always require a `/`, but I included it anyway.)
- `@{` cannot occur anywhere. Instead of a separate look-ahead check we could also have modified `$base` thus:

  ```
  my $base = qr{ [!"#\$%&'()+,\-0-9;<=>A-Z\]_`a-z{|}] | \@ (?! \{ ) }x;
  ```
- There must be at least two parts, separated by `/`.
- The whole thing cannot end with `.`.

Translation to e.g. C# is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Comment: Apparently there is a match where there shouldn't be. [Here](regexr.com/7sgg3) I tried to write the regex in the explicit form, and it doesn't pass the first test. Did I make a mistake while writing the final regex, or there indeed is a mistake in the answer?